# Sudden 503s on OpenShift Django. Need help debugging

Tags: django, server, openshift

Today accessing my Django 1.4 app on OpenShift started throwing 503 errors 99% of time when accessing it (yeah, ~1% of the time it loads fine). `htop` doesn't show any huge workload and the logs don't show any errors.

Any recommandations on how to debug this?

./manage.py shell works fine on the server and even theh PostgreSQL 9.2 db is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned that there's nothing in the logs, but I would anyway try tailing all the logs `rhc tail <yourApp>` and watching in real time for any clues there, when the 503's are returned.

To check whether your gear is not restarting due to insufficient memory, I recommend [this](https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues).
Having your ssh connection closed unexpectedly may be another indicator of unexpected gear restarts.

Note that `htop` displays only your tasks, which take only little resources in context of the whole node; using e.g. 3% of memory of 16GB may be nearing the small gear's limits (512 MB).

Comment: If the exception is coming from inside of Django, tailing log files may not help as by default Django will not log exceptions. So they need to ensure that have setup Django to log details of exceptions or alternatively have the exception details mailed to them.